# PyCharm: The project at ... uses a non-standard layout and cannot be attached to this project

Tags: pycharm

I have the latest version of PyCharm installed (2017.1). Everything works well except when I try to open two projects in the same window. I get this popup after hitting `OK` in the `Open Project` dialogue (which gives you the option to `Open in a new window` or `Open in current window`).

[image]

I tried the fix mentioned [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205408470-Multiple-projects-inside-one-window-idea-uses-a-non-standard-layout-and-cannot-be-attached-to-this-project-) (which is really stupid anyway). Also tried throwing a `*.iml` file in the `./idea` directory, but it gave me this:

```
5/4/17
5:11 PM Load Settings
                Cannot load settings from file '/home/brandon/Downloads/chalice/.idea/chalice.iml': content truncated
                File content will be recreated
```

Again, it doesn't matter which project I want to open, so replace `chalice` with `*`. Opening single `*.py` files is fine, but I can't open projects.

Anyone have a solution so I can get back to writing Python? :D

---

EDIT: So now I've downloaded the latest version PyCharm and re-installed it. Now I can't even create a new project without this popup coming up.

What's going on here ???

Comment: Similar issue with PyCharm 2019.1. What did work for me was to first open the project in new window. Afterwards I was able to attach it to existing window.

Comment: This worked for me too (open in a new window, close, reopen and attach). Easiest solution in my opinion.

Comment: Reproduced in 2023.3.2 Professional Edition; none of the solutions here worked for me; I had to re-clone the repo

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned by [norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792869/pycharm-the-project-at-uses-a-non-standard-layout-and-cannot-be-attached-to#comment97766339_43792869), for Pycharm 2019.1, first open the project in a new window.

Afterward, try to attach it to the existing window.

Answer (score 5):

I created a new project in PyCharm and had this problem.  Following [this solution](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205408470/comments/115000166230), I found the new project did not have a `.iml` file in the new project's `.idea` folder.  I copied and pasted the `.iml` from another project and just changed the `.iml` file name to match the project.  Problem solved.

Comment: Though some stuff are messed up, like I get a bracket next to the project name which is from the other project, which I took the iml from. But the project definitely loads. Good! Tnx.

Comment: this easiest solution and it works. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm support suggested that I comment out the `ProjectModuleManager` component from `~/.PyCharm2017.1/config/options/project.default.xml`. After restarting PyCharm (2017.1.3) and removing any `.idea/` directories from the modules I wanted to open, I no longer had this issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Delete the .idea folder from the second project you want to add (if it exists)
- Close the first project in current window (if opened)
- Create a New Project from existing scripts for the second project that you want to add (creates a new .idea folder)
- Open the first project and attache to it the second project

Comment: I have removed the .idea of both projects and started afresh. It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I re-edit the .xml in .idea folder for the folder that I intend to attach. The .xml file is shown as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../folder_name">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../folder_name" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```